# Casting '__unsafe_unretained id *' to 'const void **'

Tags: objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

I'm trying to achieve `[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:frames forKeys:items]` but with a CFDictionary so I have control over the key and value callbacks. This is what I've got:

```
__unsafe_unretained id keys[itemCount];
[items getObjects:keys range:NSMakeRange(0, itemCount)];
__unsafe_unretained id values[itemCount];
[frames getObjects:values range:NSMakeRange(0, itemCount)];
CFDictionaryCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, (const void **)keys, (const void **)values, itemCount, &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks, &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);
```

Which gives the following error: `Cast of an indirect pointer to an Objective-C pointer to 'const void **' is disallowed with ARC`.

I've tried various permutations of bridging, but I can't seem to get it to compile without complaint.

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't been able to find a syntax for that either. (EDIT: Justin's answer has the syntax.) Try this instead:

```
void *keys[itemCount];
[items getObjects:(__unsafe_unretained id *)(void *)keys range:NSMakeRange(0, itemCount)];
```

Then you don't need a cast when you call `CFDictionaryCreate`.

Comment: Didn't think of adding (__unsafe_unretained id *) before (void *), but it worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply cast it to `void*` at this point:

```
CFDictionaryRef d = CFDictionaryCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                        (void*)keys,
                        (void*)values,
                        itemCount,
                        &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks,
                        &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);
```

You may also consider this approach:

```
const void* keys[itemCount];
CFArrayGetValues((__bridge CFArrayRef)items, CFRangeMake(0, itemCount), keys);
const void* values[itemCount];
CFArrayGetValues((__bridge CFArrayRef)frames, CFRangeMake(0, itemCount), values);

CFDictionaryRef d = CFDictionaryCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                       keys,
                                       values,
                                       itemCount,
                                       &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks,
                                       &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);
```

Comment: Your casts won't work under ARC (as of Xcode 4.3.2), and he explained that he wants to use CFDictionary so he can change the callbacks.

Comment: You're right. I never actually tried it *without* putting in `__bridge` until your comment.  Your cast works.  With `__bridge` it fails.

Comment: @robmayoff cool. thanks for reminding me about the custom callbacks -- i have provided an alternative alternative :)

Answer (score 0):

try `(__bridge const void **)keys`.

Comment: Incompatible types casting '__unsafe_unretained id *' to 'const void **' with a __bridge cast